# Android Parent Activity History Stack Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Imagine this activity history stack:

**A > B > C > D**

A is parent to B

B is parent to D

C is optional

If I set the parents as such and navigate in order, everything works as I need it to in terms of navigating backwards (Up versus Back):

**Forward** : A > B > C > D

**Up**      : D > B > A

**Back**    : D > C > B > A

However, if I skip B...

**Forward** : A > D

**Up**      : D > A - **Why doesn't D launch B, like D > B > A, adhering to the manifest parent?**

**Back**    : D > A

Do I need to synthesize a back stack at app start?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.worked.navigation_flow">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".A"
            android:label="A">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".B"
            android:label="B"
            android:parentActivityName=".A" />
        <activity
            android:name=".C"
            android:label="C" />
        <activity
            android:name=".D"
            android:label="D" 
            android:parentActivityName=".B"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Activity Up Button**

```
public void onUp(View view) {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

Comment: try adding android:noHistory = "false" under the application element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you can see, `navigateUpFromSameTask` only try to find the parent on the same Task, however on your case A > D, B is not created, thus not in the task, and it would not create and launch the parent.

To do this, you can use TaskStackBuilder when calling D from A

```
TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
                    // followed by DetailsActivity itself
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(new Intent(this, D.class))
                    .startActivities();
```

Comment: Works great... I just dug deeper into the docs and discovered this myself as well.  Very handy!

Comment: I've added a sample project to github as well : https://github.com/work-ed/task_stack_builder